# Weierstrass theorem on determining if function have min and max

Tags: optimization, continuity, convex-optimization

The Weierstrass theorem suggest that in order for a function $f$ to have a min and max value, the following must hold:

1. $f$ must be continous over the domain
2. Domain should be closed and bounded (i.e. compact)

Example:

$ \min (x^2 + y^2)$

$ {\rm s.t.}~ x + y = 3 $

In this example it is clear that the set is not bounded since the values for x and y can be basically anthing.

However, for more complex examples it is hard to determine if a set is bounded and also closed. I am working on the following:

1. $ \max (x + y^2)$

   $ {\rm s.t.}~ 3x^2 + 5y \geq -1 , x + y^2 \leq -1 $
2. $ \max (2x + y)$

   $ {\rm s.t.}~ x^2 + y^2 \leq 9 , x + y = 1 $
3. $ \max (x+ \ln y)$

   $ {\rm s.t.}~ x-5y \geq -1 , x + y^2 \leq 1 $

Can someone help to determine whether Weierstrass theorem holds for the above optimization problems and most importantly how one can approach these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not graph each region in the xy plane? Once that's done it should be clear which are closed and bounded. Also: you should check if the last one makes sense, since the domain of the log requires $y>0.$

Comment: I think that is exactly my problem :) it is hard for me to plot these inequalites without using a computer.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a graphing calculator, or is the situation that you are not allowed to use one for some reason? [if this is for a grade, it shouldn't be put here]

Comment: The first one can be seen to be unbounded, by taking $y=0,$ so constraints are $3x^2\ge -1$ [true for any x] and $x \le -1,$ true for $x \in  (-\infty,-1].$ The second is contained in the disc radius 3 about origin. The third region might have problems because of the log term, but I haven't gone into it.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to play with the inequalities so that you always have a different variable on a different side.

E.g. with the first one we have $3x^2 + 5y \geq -1$ and $x+y^2\leq -1$. We can re-arrange so that $3x^2 \geq -1-5y$ and $x\leq -1-y^2$.

Now, the first inequality means that $3x^2$ is large (depending on $y$), and the second says that $x$ is small (depending on $y$).

Since these two conditions can always be true, this means that the set is not bounded. To prove that formally, just take $y=0$ (or anything really), and now try to build a sequence of $x_n$'s satisfying the equation with $|x_n|\rightarrow \infty$. One way to do so is that $x_n = -n$, then $x_n\leq -1$, but $3x^2 = 3n^2 \geq -1$. Then $(-n,0)$ is a diverging sequence so the set is not compact.

Sometimes however you will have constraints. For instance in the second equation $x^2+y^2 \leq  9$, this is already a bound on $x$ and $y$ (by definitino $\|(x,y)\|\leq 3$ for all $(x,y)$ in the set).

*Informally, the bounded situation can "only" happen in this trivial way, so if you see only inequalities and either $x$ and $y$ are not squared, I would try to disprove the claim.*